# What's wrong with my (pointer based) mergesort?

Tags: c++, mergesort

No errors, just doesn't sort the list. It worked when I used indices instead of pointers directly.
I feel like I'm missing something about the way pointer's should behave... . Am I correct in assuming that the pointers are passed by value (copied) into the recursive calls, or am I messing them up down the way?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void merge(int *start, int *pivot, int *end) {
    const int n = start - end;
    int ret[n];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        if (*start < *pivot) {
            ret[i] = *(start++);
        }
        else {
            ret[i] = *(pivot++);
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<n;++i) {
        start[i] = ret[i];
    }
}

void sort1(int* start,int* end) {
    int n = end - start;
    if (n <= 1) {
        return;
    }
    int* pivot = &start[n/2];
    sort1(start,pivot);
    sort1(pivot,end);
    merge(start,pivot,end);
}

int main() {
    int x[] = {1,3,6,2,4,5};
    sort1(x,x+6);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<6; ++i) {
        cout << x[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

My current output is `1 1 3 3 1 1`

Comment: I don't see an obvious problem with your code from just reading it.  Can you post the current output you are getting?

Comment: Output is just
`1\n
    3\n
    6\n
    2\n
    4\n
5\n`

Comment: since fixing the computation for `n`, it's now `1 1 3 3 1 1`

Comment: I think that you spending 5 minutes sitting in front of the Visual Studio debugger will bear more fruit than all of us trying to guess where your bug(s) are.

Comment: Modifying `pivot` affects your `if (*start < *pivot)` calculation, you realize that right?

Comment: @rcgldr: Why would what an `int*` points to ever be NULL? (Agreed about `pivot` being a lousy name.)

Comment: @ScottHunter - sort1 could include NULL checks for bad pointers. The other issue is reusing variables in merge and no bounds checking. I added an answer.

Comment: When you don't/won't try the debugger, you might try printing debug info.  Consider the following ideas:  [static int r = 0;  std::cout << "\n" << r++ << " merge(" << *start << "," << *pivot << "," << *end;] and [static int r = 0; std::cout << "\n" << r++ << " sort1(" << *start << "," << *end << ")";]. And maybe mod your input: [int x[]= { 11, 32, 63, 24, 45, 56};] which contains your input appended with their original index prior to sort.  You have more than 3 logic errors in your code.

Answer (score 3):

I think your merge is at fault.  There is no bounds-testing on the two sub-arrays, so as soon as you reach the end of one array, you'll be taking values from the other (that have already been copied).

It's normal to split the code for the merge into three loops as follows:

```
int *a1 = start;
int *a2 = pivot;
int *r = &ret[0];

// Copy smallest from each sub-array
while( a1 != pivot && a2 != end ) {
    if( *a1 < *a2 ) *r++ = *a1++;
    else *r++ = *a2++;
}

// Copy remaining values from first sub-array
while( a1 != pivot ) *r++ = *a1++;

// Copy remaining values from second sub-array
while( a2 != end ) *r++ = *a2++;
```

Comment: Agreed. Note the final while-loop is not required if the eventual target is the original sequence bed (and it usually is). Those "top" elements, if any, are already in that position in the original `start..end` sequence.  Upon completion of the second loop, `std::copy(ret, r, start)` will seal the deal. Nice answer.

Comment: Good point =)  That ought to trim down running time in the case where the array is already sorted (or mostly sorted).

Answer (score 1):

merge() is reusing start and middle, some of the code advancing both pointers, while other code expecting them to be the original values. Also n should be end-start (not start-end). Note - using the stack for ret[] will be an issue for a large array. new and delete could be used instead of _alloca, or the second array allocated in main and passed as a parameter. Cleaned up example:

```
#include <iostream>
// using _alloca since VS doesn't support variable length array
#include <malloc.h>

using namespace std;

void merge(int *start, int *middle, int *end) {
    const int n = (int)(end - start);
    int *ret   = (int *) _alloca(n * sizeof(int));
    int *left  = start;
    int *right = middle;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (right >= end || left < middle && *left <= *right) {
            ret[i] = *(left++);
        } else {
            ret[i] = *(right++);
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<n;++i) {
        start[i] = ret[i];
    }
}

void sort1(int* start, int* end) {
    int n = (int)(end - start);
    if (n <= 1) {
        return;
    }
    int* middle = &start[n/2];
    sort1(start,middle);
    sort1(middle,end);
    merge(start,middle,end);
}

int main() {
    int x[] = {1,3,6,2,4,5};
    sort1(x,x+6);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<6; ++i) {
        cout << x[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your base case in `sort1` is backwards; more specifically, the computation of `n`.

Comment: haha thanks, fixed but it does exactly the same

Comment: Did you make the same mistake anywhere else?